# Why can't a socket connect to the same host multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

If we run the code below the output will be

```
Connecting to www.google.com
30 bytes were sent.
Connecting to www.google.com
We failed to connect!
Connecting to www.google.se
30 bytes were sent.
```

Why can't i connect to the same host multiple times using the same socket?

(Also the socket seems to have some sort of memory its not just the latest host it remembers all of them...)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
    client.SendTimeout = 500;
    Connect(client, "www.google.com");
    Connect(client, "www.google.com");
    Connect(client, "www.google.se");

    Console.ReadKey();

}

private static void Connect(Socket client, string hostName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + hostName);
    IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
    IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 80);

    // Connect the socket to the remote end point.
    //client.Connect(ipEndPoint);
    IAsyncResult ar = client.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, null, null);
    ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000);

    if (!client.Connected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We failed to connect!");
        return;
    }

    // Send some data to the remote device. 
    string data = "This is a string of data <EOF>";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    int bytesTransferred = client.Send(buffer);

    // Write to the console the number of bytes transferred.
    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes were sent.", bytesTransferred);

    // Release the socket.
    //client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

    client.Disconnect(true);
    if (client.Connected)
        Console.WriteLine("We failed to disconnect");
}
```

Comment: maybe google is refused the connection

Comment: Its not google if i change it to any other host the same thing happens..

Comment: It's probably due to TCP's `TIME_WAIT` and `CLOSE_WAIT` states - once a connection has been closed, there are deliberate delays built into the protocol because different packets can take different paths and so packets may still arrive after the connection is "closed". Try adding a long time delay between attempts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever added a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); as the last line in the Connect method and it didn't change the result.

Comment: That's only 10 seconds. A quick google would suggest that these wait states can last ~4 minutes.

Comment: In case of a timeout the connection attempt will still be pending. Looks like a bug. Can't you just use a fresh socket for each connection? Much simpler.

Comment: @usr yes i could use a new socket each time but im interested in why this happens, also if some one tries to avoid GC collections reusing objects is one good way...

Comment: A socket probably consists of 100 bytes or so on the managed heap. You'll have to have a lot of sockets to trigger even a single G0 GC. Anyway, you should probably respond to the bug that I reported to you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it seems you where right i added a 5 min delay instead of 10 seconds and it worked.

Comment: "In case of a timeout the connection attempt will still be pending. Looks like a bug." When you timeout the socket is still trying to connect. Yet, you immediately start the next connection attempt. That can't be good. I have no idea what even happens then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57161/discussion-between-peter-and-usr).